# SwiftUI view builder difference in ios13 and ios15

Tags: swiftui

Just started learning SwiftUI and reading a book, written around mid 2020 using **iOS13**, which says a conditional view needs to wrapped inside a view builder otherwise it won't compile because SwiftUI won't know what type of the view is. For example, it says the following **won't compile** but I just tried in Xcode 13, **iOS15** and **it compiles fine**. So has view builder been updated since iOS13?

```
struct TestView: View {
    @Binding var n: Int
    
    var body: some View {
        if n > 0 {
            Text("Tapped \(n) times.")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, the view builder has been updated. Some of the changes in SwiftUI (like this) are backwards compatible and will still compile into code usable by older versions (like iOS 13) as opposed to new API which may only be available in newer versions.

Comment: @jnpdx can you elaborate on some details in terms of the upgrade? So now it auto wraps the code into a view builder or it can now figure out how to render the view without view builder at all?

Comment: `body` has always been a view builder. The semantics of what one can do inside a view builder has changed over time. Your best bet to find specific changes is probably to look at the Swift evolution board and forums